# Is there any inbuilt stored procedure which will return the output of a query as an XML document..?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

Is there any inbuilt stored procedure in SQL-server which will return the output of a query as an XML document..?
I need to convert the result of a query or stored proc to an XML of desired format and then save the XML to a desired folder.

Comment: have you looked up the `FOR XML` functionality?

Comment: Yes, but wanted to know if we have any inbuilt Stored proc for it. And also how to save the file to some folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.
This [blog post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/12/sql-server-simple-example-of-creating-xml-file-using-t-sql/) shows some.